# Lambda expression to retrieve property which can be null

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, coalesce

Basically I've a list of elements in which I've to retrieve a property that can be either null or a costant string. Of course there is a procedural way to do this but since I'm experimenting with lambdas I want to use them.

I've tried to use this lambda:

```
td.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.BALANCE_MU)).FirstOrDefault().BALANCE_MU
```

The problem here is that sometimes all `x.BALANCE_MU`s are null, so `FirstOrDefault()` is null and trying to  access to BALANCE_MU throws an exceptiom. If all the elements are null I should return an empty string.

Is there a better way to do this staying in the lambda domain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can project results to avoid exception:

```
var balance = td.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.BALANCE_MU))
                .Select(x => x.BALANCE_MU) // select property here
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

BTW default value for string is not empty string - it is `null`. If you want to have empty string, then as @newStackExchangeInstance suggested, you can use coalescing operator:     `balance ?? ""`.

One more update. You can use oveloaded `FirstOrDefault` method if you will do projection before filtering:

```
var balance = td.Select(x => x.BALANCE_MU)
                .FirstOrDefault(b => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(b)) ?? "";
```

Comment: He asked to return an empty string if all of the values where null - not just return null.

Comment: this works:    td.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.BALANCE_MU)).Select(x => x.BALANCE_MU).FirstOrDefault() ?? ""